# display inline not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to integrate ngTimepicker with my angular project. It do work but I cannot inline the ngTimepicker inputs with the form input.
[check plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vtkq8H)

I want this part of html to be in one line.

*index.html*

```
<form>
  <input type="text " required="true" ng-model="ctrl.taskObj.condition">
  <ng-timepicker ng-model="ctrl.taskObj.timeStart" step="30" theme="green"></ng-timepicker>
  <ng-timepicker ng-model="ctrl.taskObj.timeEnd" step="30" theme="green"></ng-timepicker>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.addTask()">Add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set display inline-block to your ng-timepicker directives. Because it replaces itself with a template.

So you need to write a css [like that](https://plnkr.co/edit/zVi2c87yUFa4bNR8oziW);

```
ng-timepicker {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="app">
 <head>
<title>ngTimepicker</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">

<ng-timepicker ng-model="ctrl.time"></ng-timepicker>
{{ ctrl.time }}

<ng-timepicker ng-model="ctrl.time2" theme="red" show-meridian="true">    </ng-timepicker>
{{ ctrl.time2 }}

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/ngTimepicker.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var app = angular.module('app', ['jkuri.timepicker']);
 app.controller('Ctrl', [function() { 

 }]);
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Try something like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS

```
ng-timepicker div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Updated [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/mY41daBP4TtcypxoyxXe?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example based on your code : [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZXwlDRyguxLrymk17VUt?p=preview)

I basically changed the css class to :

```
.inline {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and put the class in your ngTimepicker directives :

```
<form>
  <input class="inline"  type="text " required="true" ng-model="ctrl.taskObj.condition">
  <ng-timepicker class="inline" ng-model="ctrl.taskObj.timeStart" step="30" theme="green"></ng-timepicker>
  <ng-timepicker class="inline" ng-model="ctrl.taskObj.timeEnd" step="30" theme="green"></ng-timepicker>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.addTask()">Add</button>
</form>
```